# Router calling with template URI parameters

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am using the `useRouter` hook.

I have templated pages in my application.

I have a `useEffect` hook responding to `router` and making an API call.

I am trying to forward the entire URL to `/api/${path}.json${query}`

```
const u = new URL(`https://example.com${router.asPath}`)
const path = `/api${u.pathname}.json${u.search}`
```

However the router seems to fire twice, once as the template, and again as filled with parameters for instance:

1. `/[design]/[product]`
2. `/blue/shirt`

This is consequentially firing the call to the API twice.

Here's my hook:

```
export const usePage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [page, setPage] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            // the next.js query is littered with the params, so we can get
            // just the query with this:
            const u = new URL(`https://example.com${router.asPath}`)
            const path = `/api${u.pathname}.json${u.search}`
            console.log({ path })
            const results = await fetch(path, { method: 'GET' });
            const json = await results.json();
            setPage(json)
        })();
    }, [router]);
    return page;
}
```

I can wrap the call in a conditional check to see if there's `[|]` in the url, and don't run the api call. Wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: What's setting the `router.asPath` to `/[design]/[product]`? Unless you're changing the routing externally to `usePage`, that `useEffect` should only fire once.

Answer (score 0):

Band-aid solution:

```
export const usePage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [page, setPage] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            // the next.js query is littered with the params, so we can get
            // just the query with this:
            const u = new URL(`https://example.com${router.asPath}`)
            if (u.pathname.match(/\[/)) return;
            const path = `/api${u.pathname}.json${u.search}`
            const results = await fetch(path, { method: 'GET' });
            const json = await results.json();
            setPage(json)
        })();
    }, [router]);
    return page;
}
```